# Span and radius vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, visualization

Is it possible to get any (radius) vector in 3D using only 1 fixed radius vector and all possible radius vectors?

(Of course, every vector we get can be translated so that its starting point is at its origin).

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by a "radius vector"? What exactly do you mean by "getting" one vector using others?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: radius vector -  a vector whose starting point is the origin of the (3D) coordinate system. Suppose you have one fixed vector. Is it possible to get any other vector in 3D space with that 1 fixed radius vector and any other radius vector?

Comment: In the usual mathematical framework, there is nothing that makes a "radius vector" different from any other vector.  Also, per my second question, how exactly are we "getting" the a vector using two others? Are we taking a linear combination of them? Is there some other operation that you have in mind where we might combine two vectors to produce another?

Comment: Yes, we are talking about linear combinations

Comment: So with that said, suppose our "fixed vector" is $\mathbf x$, and our desired vector is $\mathbf y$. We could produce the vector $\mathbf y$ as the linear combination $\mathbf x + (\mathbf y - \mathbf x)$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Oh, how I missed that... Thanks